# Packet Loss/High Ping with One Computer Seems to Affect Entire Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, packet, packet-loss

I'm having an issue with my PC. I have a wireless router/modem combo box that was provided by my ISP and am having issues with a single PC on my network.

The PC is connected via WIFI and often will experience significant packet loss and very high pings sporadically. Other items on my network are just fine. I have an Apple TV, some iPads/Phones and a few laptops. My main desktop PC is connected wirelessly.

If I'm NOT using the PC, the network is fine. However sometimes when I turn the PC on it causes packet loss (50%) or higher, and often cause the entire network to fail for a period. Sometimes it seems that rebooting temporarily solves the problem, or disabling and re-enabling the network card.
([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B009VKON0S?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s01](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009VKON0S))

I'm having difficulty diagnosing what might cause such an issue. I'm a novice with networking, but understand the basic terms. Thanks for any help you might be able to provide!

Below is an example from a ping test to google:

```
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=528ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=2044ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=261ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=3481ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1444ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=2643ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=2723ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=2007ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=3362ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=116ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.    
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=409ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=2127ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=2682ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=2349ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=76ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=128ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=83ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=57
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=87ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=84ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 100, Received = 47, Lost = 53 (53% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 14ms, Maximum = 3481ms, Average = 749ms
===Ping Test Done===
Press any key to continue . . .
```

And the same time period to the router itself:

```
Pinging 192.168.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3494ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1673ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=136ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3475ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1449ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1696ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2672ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2006ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3351ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=123ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.50: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=408ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2126ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=44ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3788ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=83ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=85ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=124ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=63ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1820ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=249ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 100, Received = 48, Lost = 52 (52% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 3788ms, Average = 694ms
===Ping Test Done===
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: ping timeout does not always mean packet loss. Capture from the other side to validate whether or not that device is actually sending the ICMP replies. It may be that the device is too busy at the time to pay attention to pings. The loss seen may be induced by a heavy increase in traffic caused by the PC you are adding. As noted by Joe, this is often the result of malware. A capture on the router will tell you how much/what sort of traffic of it is hitting the router from that PC. If the router can't capture, you can use an appliance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_capture_appliance

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting "ping flooded". If you have been downloading programs then there is a chance that you picked up a corrupt file. Your laptop might have malicious code hiding in a windows program file that most anti spyware or malware programs will miss. I assume you are running windows so try this and see if it cleans up your system. It is a Microsoft program free and safe with no added garbage 
(http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/virus-malware.aspx?q=virus) 
Also check your firewall settings and open ports. You can trace an Ip address from a host of sites to see if a web browser or program on your laptop triggers ports to become active causing unwanted behavior. Here is another tool from windows to watch ports and online activity.(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897437.aspx)